# Why Past Perfect in "He had persuaded himself that the festivities were barbaric, and he made up his mind that he..."?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

> The result was that Philip had nowhere to go, and he spent Christmas Day in his lodgings. Under Hayward's influence he **had persuaded** himself that the festivities that attend this season were vulgar and barbaric, and he made up his mind that he would take no notice of the day; but when it came, the jollity of all around affected him strangely.

Of Human Bondage by W. Somerset Maugham

First question :Why "**had persuaded**"  and not "**persuaded**"? it seems obvious that this sentence happens before christmas .I don't see the necessity of past perfect here. I must be wrong, but why?

Second question: Why **persuaded** and **made up** are not both Past perfect or past simple, that seems also obvious that the persuasion is before the decision. That's because he was persuaded that he made his decision. I must be also wrong but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of past perfect is the backshifting of the action taken ***before*** the time which the fragment is describing.  It's backshifting of ***present perfect tense***.  I'll explain.

Philip was under Hayward's influence **prior** to the Christmas Day.  Under that influence, eventually, **also prior** to the Christmas Day, Philip's opinion (that the festivities were vulgar) formed.  When, hard to say exactly.  What is known, however, is that **on the day of which Maugham writes** the opinion was **already there**.

To express the action that took effect some time in the past, at an unknown moment, but of which we **have** a *definite result*, we use **present perfect**.  If we go back to that day, we can say that Philip *has persuaded himself* because the result (the opinion about the festivities) *is* apparent, but the moment of its formation is *unknown*.

If we take the description entirely into ***present tense***, we have:

> The result  ***is*** that Philip ***has*** nowhere to go, and he ***spends*** Christmas Day in his lodgings.  Under Hayward's influence he ***has persuaded*** himself ...

Now, push everything into **past tense** and you should turn "**has**" into "**had**" (twice):

> The result  ***was*** that Philip ***had<sub>1</sub>*** nowhere to go, and he ***spent*** Christmas Day in his lodgings.  Under Hayward's influence he ***had<sub>2</sub> persuaded*** himself ...

That's it.

---

Now, about why not both in the same tense (your second question).

First off, it's author's prerogative to use whatever tense seems suitable to them.  Second, if we treat the text of the book like we do Nature, we can't say what something *ought* to be.  We can only attempt to explain given the evidence.

The evidence in this case is that "made up his mind" is in *past indefinite tense*, and not in *past perfect*.  What does that tell us?  I see it that it tells us that *making up Philip's mind* most likely **coincided** with other events described.

> ... festivities **were** vulgar..., and he **made up** his mind...

To put it in present tense (as if we are there living right alongside Philip)

> ... festivities **are** vulgar..., and he **makes up** his mind (*now*) that he **will** take no notice...

That is, he didn't make up his mind before that time of which the author speaks to us.  Which time is that?  Some time soon **before** the Christmas day, probably, since there is the "*will take*". Right after that, Maugham writes "but when it came...", pointing out that the actual day followed.

In other words, we have three events, Philip persuades himself, Philip makes up his mind, Christmas day comes.  The moment of persuasion is uncertain, but in the past relative to the moment of making up the mind.  Both are in the past relative to the Christmas day.

Comment: Yes but why not backshifting  for made up because both actions took place before christmas day

Comment: Edited my answer with more details.